# iOS - Push Notification from iOS App to APNs without a server or third party

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I'm looking for a way to send the payload for remote notification to the APNs from an iOS App. i'm pretty sure there's a way, but i'm not very good when it comes to communicating with a server and Json.

i've looked into NWPusher, swift Pusher and others. i couldn't find a clear instructions.

any help would be appropriate.

thanks

Comment: NWPusher seems right for what you need. 
What's your problem exactly ? 
Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435503/nw-pusher-push-payload-ios-swift/33435887

Comment: the NWPusher as i understood take a device Token and send the notification to it. i need it to send it to all devices has that App.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all token in a database then get all token in your app to send the notifications. 
Is not possible to simply get all token of all devices using your app. Tokens must be store somewhere.

Comment: how to optain all the tokens if is an app in the App Store ?

Comment: You must update your app and add a system to store tokens in a database. 
And enable notifications on your app if is not done yet

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do it.  Push Notification is not meant be sent from your app.